# How to Transform Centroid from Pixel to Real World Coordinates

Tags: python, matrix, graphics, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am working on an application using an IFM 3D camera to identify parts prior to a robot pickup. Currently I am able to find the centroid of these objects using contours from a depth image and from there calculate the center point of these objects in pixel space.

My next task is to then transform the 2D centroid coordinates to a 3D point in 'real' space. I am able to train the robot such that it's coordinate frame is either at the center of the image or at the traditional (0,0) point of an image (top left).

The 3D camera I am using provides both an intrinsic and extrinsic matrix. I know I need to use some combination of these matrices to project my centroid into three space but the following questions remain:

1. My current understanding from googling is the intrinsic matrix is used to fix lens distortion (barrel and pinhole warping, etc.) whereas the extrinsic matrix is used to project points into the real world. Is this simplified assumption correct?
2. How can a camera supply a single extrinsic matrix? I know traditionally these matrices are found using the checkerboard corners method but are these not dependent on the height of the camera?
3. Is the solution as simple as taking the 3x4 extrinsic matrix and multiplying it by a 3x1 matrix [x, y, 1] and if so, will the returned values be relative to the camera center or the traditional (0,0) point of an image.

Thanks in advance for any insight! Also if it's any consolation I am doing everything in python and openCV.

Comment: Is your camera not at a fixed distance to the work surface? If you can’t fix the distance, you need a way to measure it (stereo, time-of-flight, etc).

Comment: It will be a fixed distance yes. Does this mean I can use the single ext. camera matrix the vendor provided?

Comment: Just calibrate the system, place objects at known locations, take a picture, and determine which pixels belong to those locations. Sure you can complicate it more, but simple is always better.

Comment: Will do, I will preform a calibration. In regards to the intrinsic/extrinsic matrix supplied by the vendor, I'm trying to wrap my head around why these are provided if they are not height agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. I suggest you read the basics in Multiple View Geometry of Hartley and Zisserman, freely available in the web. Dependent on the camera model, the intrinsics contain different parameters. For the pinhole camera model, these are the focal length and the principal point.
2. The only reason why you maybe could directly transform your 2D centroid to 3D is that you use a 3D camera. Read the manual of the camera, it should be explained how the relation between 2D and 3D coordinates is given for your specific model.
   If you have only image data, you can only compute a 3D point from at least two views.
3. No, of course not. Please don't be lazy and start reading the basics about camera projection instead of asking for others to explain the common basics that are written down everywhere in the web and literature.

Comment: Hi, while I appreciate you taking the time to respond, please note that I have in fact done research online. I'm using this forum to confirm my understanding of the topic through a channel other than papers, articles or textbooks. I do not have a background in CV. You clearly do. Please do not assume that your 'common basics' are the same as everyone else. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: "my current understanding from googling is the intrinsic matrix is used to fix lens distortion" - This statement showed that you did not read at least a few pages in a book about intrinsic parameters. So please go for it and you will quickly understand. Your questions are very broad and not the best way to address stackoverflow. Please be more specific so that the answers can be more specific too. In addition, please accept or upvote answers.